# How to send vehicle over obstacles?

Tags: surviving-mars

How to send vehicle over obstacles ?

Obviously, there are multiple zones on the map that cannot be reached without a certain technology or building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What obstacles do you mean? The rovers can usually drive around any obstacles.

There are of course craters and large ridges, which cannot be accessed normally. To get there you have to build a tunnel.

Start the tunnel on one side of the ridge and put the other end on the side accessible to you, your drones will build it, then you can send rovers to the other side.

Make sure to connect the tunnels with both power cables and pipes. This connects them to your network and you can use the power/water/oxygen on the other side.

Comment: Also Note: if one tunnel entrance is destroyd for example by a meteor strike, the other one will be destroyed too.

Comment: Adding to this, you can also use the Ramp tool to have your drones construct a ramp to a higher or lower area